# How do I point password reset to my own templates?

Tags: django

In my `urls.py`, I have:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
urlpatterns += [
    url("^reset-password/$", auth_views.password_reset, 
        {
            "template_name": "pages/password_reset_form.html"
        },
        name="reset_pw"
    ),
]
```

My `password_reset_form.html` has this:

```
            <form id="reset-pw-form" name="resetPWForm" method="post" action="{% url 'reset_pw' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input
                    id="id_email"
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="Enter email"
                    name="email"
                    required>
                <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
            </form>
```

When you hit the submit button on the form, it POSTs to `/reset-password`, then GETs `/password_reset/done/`. How can I make it GET `/reset-password/done` and load `my_template.html` instead?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please elaborate

Comment: After the POST request to `/reset-password/`, Django GETs `/password_reset/done`, which loads a default Django template stating the password reset link is being emailed. Instead of loading the Django template, I want to load my own template with an "email on the way" message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to do so:

**A. Using custom class**

1) Create a custom url to handle a custom class made in views.py

```
url(r'^reset/done/$', views.PasswordResetComplete.as_view(),name='password_reset_complete'),
```

2) Import PasswordResetCompleteView and inherit it on the custom class made. Pass a template_name = "Your template.html"

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetCompleteView

class PasswordResetComplete(PasswordResetCompleteView):
    template_name = "template name"
```

**B. Overriding templates**

1) Create a registration folder inside your django templates folder

2) Create your custom template with a name "password_reset_confirm.html", why this name because the django reset done view has a same template name which will get override.

Comment: For method B, would I have to put the HTML file in one of Django's system folders, or in my own `templates/registration` in my Django project?

Comment: In your own templates/registeration

Comment: I used method B, but the template is "password_reset_confirm.html"

Comment: I mean to say to put that html file like this: templates/registration/password_reset_done.html :) Anyways if the answer helped, can you accept it on the post. Thanks

Comment: Whoops, I posted that wrong. The correct template I needed to override was "password_reset_done.html"

Comment: @Username sorry my bad too, i forgot you were asking for done and not confirm :p